# How to increase stream_set_timeout() in php

Tags: php, sockets

I am sending push message to iPhone devices Through steam_socket using php.It's working fine but i want to send a 1000 records at time in that case i get only 50 messages then i get `Warning: stream_set_timeout():`
how could i increase stream socket time is there any way to handle this type problem can any one please guide me.

here is my code

```
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++)
{
$gstr="3f3dad52b4fb50001cb223253a3d995542209d354eXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

pushMessage($gstr,$_REQUEST['msg'].$i,"Thinkingofyou");
}

    function pushMessage($deviceToken,$message,$app) {
        echo "Sending iPhone Push Notifications to " . $deviceToken . "<br /><br />";
        echo "Your Message: " . $message . "<br />";
        $time = time();
        $apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com'; 
        $apnsPort = 2195;
        $apnsCert = 'aps-toyPush.pem';
        $streamContext = stream_context_create();

     stream_set_timeout($streamContext, 3600);
        stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
        //stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
        $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

        if($apns) {
                $payload = array();

                $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $message, 'badge' => 1, 'sound' => 'default');



                $payload = json_encode($payload);
                $apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
                fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);
        } else { 
                echo "Connection Failed - iPhone Push Notifications Server";
                echo $errorString."<br />";
                echo $error."<br />";
        }
    //  socket_close($apns);
        fclose($apns);
    }
```

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from a user's post in the PHP manual:

```
<?php
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec'=>$sec, 'usec'=>$usec));
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array('sec'=>$sec, 'usec'=>$usec));
?>
```